# C place interface in header file while hiding the functions which implement it

Tags: c

I want to make an interface to a system call handler but I don't want to declare the functions implementing it in the header file as well.

I want them to be `static`, within the `syscall.c` (the source file) rather than being declared in `syscall..h` (the header file).

Is there any way of achieving this?
Also, do you know of any C books touching upon this subject?

```
//container of pointers to the functions executing the system call
typedef struct
{
   void     (*halt)     (void);
   void     (*exit)     (int status);
   pid_t    (*exec)     (const char *file);
   int      (*wait)     (pid_t pid);
   bool     (*create)   (const char *file, int initial_size);
   bool     (*remove)   (const char *file);
   int      (*open)     (const char *file);
   int      (*filesize) (int fd);
   int      (*read)     (int fd, void *buffer, int length);
   int      (*write)    (int fd, const void *buffer, int length);
   void     (*seek)     (int fd, int position);
   int      (*tell)     (int fd);
   void     (*close)    (int fd);
}td_sys_call_handler;



//points to system call handling functions
static td_sys_call_handler syscall_redirect =
{
  .halt     = fu_halt,
  .exit     = fu_exit,
  .exec     = fu_exec,
  .wait     = process_wait,
  .create   = fu_create,
  .remove   = fu_remove,
  .open     = fu_open,
  .filesize = fu_file_filesize,
  .read     = fu_read,
  .write    = fu_write,
  .seek     = fu_file_seek,
  .tell     = fu_file_tell,
  .close    = fu_file_close,
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the header, declare:

```
extern td_sys_call_handler syscall_redirect;
```

and in the implementation (`syscall.c`), just define the structure as a normal global variable — but *don't* make it `static`.  (A `static` variable has internal linkage, so it can't be referred to by other modules, but the whole point of this structure is for other modules to use it.)

Comment: Just what I was going to say.  N.B. `syscall_redirect` should probably be declared `const`.